# Adding Hyphen in row data in python

Tags: python, csv

In my csv file, i have a col with value like 
A12001
A22001
A32001

I need to make it look like

A1-2001
A2-2001
A3-2001

I am new to python. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit pls.  What is s here exactly. I got the logical thing though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you CSV file is made of, so for simplicity sake I will assume that your CSV file has only this column.

So,

1 - Open your CSV file for read & write, assuming its name myCSV.csv

2 - read each line and re-write it with the modified string.

3 - Close the CSV file

```
with open('myCSV.csv','rb+') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line: break #Break of While loop when reaching EOF(End Of File)
        f.seek(-len(line),1) #Set current file position to beginning of current line
        line = line[:2] + '-' + line[2:] #modify your string
        f.write(line) #write modified line
        f.flush() #make the write happen
```

Comment: Glad for you...if you are happy with the answer then you might want to select it as the right answer..:)

Answer (score 0):

For each string value `sv` in the column you can use

```
newval = sv[:2] + '-' + sv[2:]
```